# SSIS Packages and TFS post-merge-script?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, merge, ssis, package

I'm running packages on the sql-server from the filesystem.
Now we want to integrade tfs as a version control.
So basically the foldero n the server containing the packages has to be identical to the release-branch in the tfs.
Is there any way to e.g. copy the files on merge to the server?

So basically:

Release-> Branch to Dev -> Edit Packages -> Merge to Release ->Copy Packages from TFS to destination

Is it possible to add a "post-merge-script" that copies the files?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After you check in the packages/files to TFS, it will be easy to get them to a workspace.

You can create a workspace on your destination machine, then perform [downloading (getting) files from the Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/download-get-files-from-server) in VS, or use [Get command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-command) to get the packages/files.

Comment: Thank you for your fast request. My description was a little bit false. I want automate the whole procedure and not get the packages manuelly. Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the packages automatically to a workspace when you merge to Release branch? How do you merge to Release branch? In VS?

Comment: There is no such automatic procedure by default. You need to create a Server-side event handler to listen to a Check-in event, when there is a check-in notification for Release branch, perform get latest action. You ma get start from this article: http://www.almguide.com/2011/12/tfs-server-side-event-handlers/